# Angular Upload image as multipart formdata (NestJS Backend)

Tags: javascript, angular, http, ionic-framework, nestjs

I'm trying to post an image using formdata to a nestJS powered backend and running into issues where the formdata is undefined when it reaches the backend. I tried uploading an image using postman and it worked as intended.

Here is my code for the Front end:

```
let blob = this.getBlob(results[i], ".png");
const file = new File([blob],name, {type:"image/png"});
let  postData = new FormData();

postData.append('file', file);

this.httpService.uploadUserPhoto(postData)
    .subscribe(res =>{
      console.log(res)
  }, error => {
 console.log(error);
this.unknownError(error.name);
})
```

And The Http Call

```
uploadUserPhoto(data: FormData){
   return this.http.post(`${this.config.serverAddress}/api/user/photoUpload`, data)
 }
```

The Backend uses the built in File Intreceptor to handle the image, Docs: 
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload

```
@Post('photoUpload')
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    uploadFile(@User() user, @UploadedFile() file) {
        return this.profileService.saveFile(user,file)
    }
```

And The code for saving the uploaded image (to google cloud)

```
private fileUploader(userId: string, uploadedFile: any): Observable<any> {
     return new Observable(observer => {
           const fileName = `${userId}:${uniqId()}`;
           const file = this.photoBucket.file(fileName);

           const stream = file.createWriteStream({
                metadata: {
                  contentType: uploadedFile.mimetype
                 },
              resumable: false
        });
```

And Here is the error that the file intrecptor throws:

```
[Nest] 26603   - 10/28/2019, 5:38:34 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'mimetype' of undefined +106042ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mimetype' of undefined
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.observer [as _subscribe] (PATH/dist/services/user.profile.service.js:53:47)
```

And Again, uploading the image file using postman works!
Thanks...

Comment: Could you point out which line this is, please : services/user.profile.service.js:53:47

Comment: @thinkwinwin Hi, ive edited the question to point to that code

Comment: `uploadedFile` is undefined, what are you passing to this function when calling it?

Comment: @thinkwinwin yeah, uploading the image postman works as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out a solution for this. First of all, rather than getting a file url, get base64 from the ionic image picker. Then you create a blob from that base64 and append its content type. You can do this in any way you like but i did it via a node module, b64-to-blob (https://www.npmjs.com/package/b64-to-blob). After that, you create a form data from it and finally, http post.

Here's the code:

```
if (this.user.photos.length < 5) {
            this.imagePicker.getPictures({
                maximumImagesCount: 1,
                quality: 50,
                outputType: 1
            })
                .then((results: string[]) => {
                    results.forEach(res => {
                        const contentType = 'image/png';
                        // @ts-ignore
                        let blob = b64toBlob(res, contentType);
                        let fd: FormData = new FormData();
                        fd.append('file', blob);
                        this.httpUpload(fd)
                    })

                }, (err) => {
                    this.unknownError(err);
                });

        }
```